# Python IMAP search, it does not work

Tags: python-2.7

I try search some mail,but it does not work, my code:
`

```
conn = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL('imap.qq.com',993)

# login
try:
    conn.login(config.MAIL_ADDRESS, config.MAIL_PASSWORD)
except Exception as err:
    print 'connect fail: ',err
conn.select("inbox")
typ, data = conn.search(None,'(SUBJECT "test")')
print"UID list length is %i" % len(string.split(data[0]))`
```

run this code, it can print all mails. It seems search does not work.
I do not know where is wrong.I use python 2.7

Comment: "Does not work" is not something anyone can work with. Is there an error message? What is the expected outcome? What is the actual outcome?

Comment: @user2722968 Thank you for your reply. "Does not work" means the expected outcome. No matter what my filter writes, the output is all the mail.

Comment: Your code runs fine (it returns a subset of messages with the subject conforming to the criteria). There's something wrong with the server you're trying to use - maybe check out the log files on the server side to see if you find any indication of a problem.